# Decoherence: Does the environment must be a tensor product of two sub-systems to remove any ambiguity?

Tags: decoherence, foundations

In decoherence theory, we describe the decoherence of a system $S$ by the mean of an interaction with an environment. In short, if I consider: $|\psi_S \rangle=a|0_S\rangle+b|1_S\rangle$, the system will interact with the environment and I will have:

$$\left( a|0_S\rangle + b|1_S\rangle \right) |0_E\rangle \rightarrow a|0_S0_E(t)\rangle +b|1_S1_E(t)\rangle$$

Tracing out the environment, we have, with $r(t)=\langle 1_E(t) | 0_E(t) \rangle$

$$\rho_{S}=|a|^2 |0\rangle \langle 0| + |b|^2 |1 \rangle \langle 1 | +ab^* r(t) |0\rangle \langle  1| + a^*b r^*(t) |1\rangle \langle 0 |$$

On a short timescale, we will have $r(t) \approx 0$, the final state of the system will be a classical mixture. This is usually how we describe decoherence process.

When we talk about a measurement process, replacing $E$ by an apparatus $A$ leaves an un-satisfactory explanation. Indeed if my environment played the role of an apparatus, I would have for the global state, assuming the process completly killed the coherence of the system, and modelling for simplicity the apparatus as a two level system:

$$|\psi_{SA}\rangle= a|0_S0_A\rangle + b|1_S1_A\rangle$$

In the particular case $a=b=1$, this state is also $|++\rangle +|--\rangle$. The measurement is then ill-defined (did we measure $\sigma_x$, or $\sigma_z$: it looks the same in those two basis !). **I call it the "what did we measure" problem in what follows.**

A way to solve this issue is then to use a third system (the environment) that will remove such ambiguity. Basically at the end we will have a $SAE$ state: $a|0_S0_A0_E\rangle + b|1_S1_A1_E\rangle$ which because of the third system removes all ambiguity (I don't go in the details but this is a result from tri-orthogonal decomposition theorem).

### **My question is:**

I totally understand the "what did we measure" problem with the apparatus. But then it should also be a conceptual problem for a "natural" decoherence (i.e system interacting with environment). However in all environmental decoherence study I looked we always assume system+environment as the total system of study. We do not include some extra part to remove this issue.

Is this ambiguity implicitly removed by the fact the environment $E$ is actually composed of many sub-systems. Basically: $H_E = H_{E_1} \otimes H_{E_2}$, and the state is actually something like:

$$|\psi_{SE_1E_2}\rangle= a|0_S0_{E_1}0_{E_2}\rangle + b|1_S 1_{E_1}1_{E_2}\rangle$$

And I can then interpret the decoherence as a measurement process as well (the part $E_1$ of the environment measured my system).

Would you agree that it is precisely the fact we can "factorise" the environment into two sub-environment that explains the fact we don't have a "what did we measure" problem with the environment ?

Comment: We [can prove](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/465739) the uniqueness of such a form for the state if we assume a fixed tripartite factorization of the Hilbert space, but if we don't assume that, then uniqueness is lost (and the proof is easy). So if you're asking whether the ability to factorize the environment *at all* solves the what-did-we-measure problem, the answer would be no; but if you're asking whether *fixing* a factorization of the environment solves the what-did-we-measure problem, the answer would be yes. Are you asking either of these questions? Or something else?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly thank you for your answer. If I understand you correctly: I must assume to have a tensor product of three (or more right ?) terms to remove this ambiguity. If on the other hand I do not assume this, I could have a particular case in which only two hilbert space are considered: $S$ and $E$ as a whole. And in this case there is still the ambiguity. But the thing is that the physics shouldn't depend on the way I want to write down the vector (which is implicit somehow in our discussion). The basis ambiguity should either be removed or not.

Comment: Then my question is: in practice in environmental decoherence, when people usually explain it with two Hilbert space (system+environment), should it actually be understood as the fact environment is composed of many sub-systems and the basis ambiguity is removed because of them ? How to make sense of basis ambiguity with environmental decoherence ?

Comment: Maybe I will formulate my question differently: to have a well defined environmental decoherence model, **do we need to have a well defined physics to have an environment composed of at least two hilbert space so that the ambiguity can be removed ? Is it implicit in all decoherence model in which there are only system and environmental hilbert space ?** Because there is a great emphasis about this problem when talking about measuring apparatus but the problem seems like forgotten when we study environmental decoherence which I find weird.

Comment: Having at least two factors in the environment is necessary (so the answer to your comment is yes), but my point was that it's not sufficient. If the factorization of the environment's Hilbert space is not fixed, then the number of factors is irrelevant: the basis ambiguity remains no matter how many factors we allow. This is related to the fact that a $N^K$-dimensional Hilbert space can be factorized into a number $K$ of $N$-dimensional Hilbert spaces in uncountably-infinitely many different ways. Not only is $K\geq 2$ environment-factors required, but those factors must also be *fixed*.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I am not sure to understand your point actually. Is it related to the fact that for example the two qubit state $|00\rangle$ can be seen as a vector of 1 two-qubit Hilbert space, or a tensor product of vector living each of them in 1 qubit Hilbert space ? Could you elaborate more on what you said about uncoutably infinitely many different ways ? Thanks !

Comment: Let $H_E$ be the Hilbert space of the environment, and let's say it's $N^3$-dimensional. Choose any orthonormal basis for this Hilbert space and label each of those basis vectors with a unique $3$-tuple of numbers $(l,m,n)$, each of which goes from $1$ and $N$. That defines a factorization $H_E=H_A\otimes H_B\otimes H_C$ in which those basis vectors are represented by $|l\rangle\otimes |m\rangle\otimes |n\rangle$. Since $H_E$ has an uncountably-infinite number of different orthonormal bases, this construct gives us an uncountably-infinite number of different $3$-way factorizations of $H_E$.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I agree with the math in your last comment. However I am still not totally clear with the global message. Let's say that the evolution gives $|0_S0_E\rangle + |1_S1_E\rangle$ where the environment states are orthogonal, and $N=4$. If I understand you correctly, I could factorize my environment into many different states. For example I could choose the mapping: $|0_E\rangle=|00\rangle$, and $|1_E\rangle=|11\rangle$. But I could also choose: $|0_E\rangle=|00\rangle+|11\rangle$ and $|1_E\rangle=|00\rangle-|11\rangle$. In the first case the ambiguity is removed but not in the second

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Is it what you mean ? Then, I am not sure to know how to interpret all this. Does that mean that there must have a privileged basis in which I can base my physical interpretations on, to know if the ambiguity is removed ? I would not be so surprized by this, for instance if we consider two photons, the tensor product of local basis allow to base interpretations (basically to know if two particles are entangled depends on how we define local basis).

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly But actually a more basic problem I have is: do we actually have a basis problem at all with the environment ? Indeed, it is not "supposed" to measure the state of the system. So in the end, isn't having a good local description for $S$ enough to solve issues of interpretations ? Let's assume that $S+E$ state is $|00\rangle+|11\rangle = |++\rangle + |--\rangle$, is it a problem in the end ? As the local density matrix for both will be correct. The environment is not assumed to have measure neither $\sigma_z$ or $\sigma_x$ so we do not really need to interpret it ?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly In the opposite of the measuring apparatus in which we know that they must be correlated **in the good basis**, we don't conceptually need to ask it for the environment-system correlation. We thus need that local density matrix are correct. Would you agree ?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation of my previous comment is exactly right. The significance of all this is that in order to solve the what-did-we-measure problem, we need to know which environment-observables can and cannot be measured in practice. Choosing a fixed factorization of the environment's Hilbert space is a mathematically-easy way of saying "we can't possibly measure any environment-observables that act non-trivially on more than one of these factors," and that ensures that nothing we do in the future can ever mix the two terms in the superposition. It ensures that the decoh'ce is permanent.

Comment: What happens in the environment is important because that's what ensures that the decoherence really is permanent. For example, suppose that I have a system of three photons. I can put their polarizations into a GHZ state $|000) + |111)$ and treat the second and third photons as part of the "environment," but that does *not* mean that the polarization of the first photon has been measured, because the transformation that led to this entangled state can easily be un-done. The key question is this: is what happened in the environment practically irreversible or not?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Sorry I'm boring but I still have questions. First, the fact that "natural" decoherence is irreversible is just a "practical" thing: because it would be super complicated to tune the interaction properly between a system and all its environment. But as the dynamic explaining it is fully Hamiltonian it could be possible. Thus I am not sure to understand the relationship between the fixed factorization we choose and the fact it is taken to ensure decoherence is permanent.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Also, I agree that what happens to the environment is important. And that we need to know its state. But I'm not sure to get what you mean with your GHZ state. I agree that in such state the two last photons did not measure the two first ones. But at the same time, as far as I understood, the decoherence theory would model a measurement of the state $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ by entangling it to an environment such that it becomes $|000\rangle+|111\rangle$ where the two last Hilbert space are environmental ones. You want to say that because it can be undone easily it cannot model a

Comment: measurement process ? I am not sure to understand why the "easy/not easy" undoing criteria should say wether or not it is a measurement.